# How Add String or Word after Javascript function Runs?

Tags: javascript

I Have A script in Which I am Getting No. of Days in my input Field... For Example

**Input Feild Date2 - Input field date2 = input field result in number (like 20, 30 ,40)**

What I Am Looking For is

Input Field Date2 - Input field date1 = input field result in number With String After That (like 20 **Days**, 30 **Days**,40 **Days**)

Please Help to Know How Can I Add String or Word so that I receive word days by default on every output

My Javascript Code is given Below

Code:

```js
function GetDays() {
  var dropdt = new Date(document.getElementById("course_end_date").value);
  var pickdt = new Date(document.getElementById("admission_date").value);
  return parseInt((dropdt - pickdt) / (24 * 3600 * 1000));
}

function cal() {
  if (document.getElementById("course_end_date")) {
    document.getElementById("course_duration").value = GetDays();
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you include your HTML. The snippet is not working right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you triggering the calculation happening? My best guess without seeing more of your code is that you're doing it before the elements are populated with values? I've copied a snippet below which is identical to your javascript with what I believe to be similar to your html that works when you trigger the calculation on a button click. For example, when running the snippet if you input `1/1/2020` for the admission date and `2/1/2020` for the course end date it displays 31 days.

```js
function GetDays() {
  var dropdt = new Date(document.getElementById("course_end_date").value);
  var pickdt = new Date(document.getElementById("admission_date").value);
  return parseInt((dropdt - pickdt) / (24 * 3600 * 1000));
}

function cal() {
  if (document.getElementById("course_end_date").value) {
    document.getElementById("course_duration").value = GetDays() + " days";
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="admission_date" type="date" placeholder="Admission Date">
<input id="course_end_date" type="date" placeholder="Course End Date">
<p>
<label for="course_duration">Course Duration</label>
<input id="course_duration" type="text" readonly>
<button onclick="cal()">Calculate Duration</button>
</p>
```